# How do I replace the tflites in Tensorflow's image classification example for Android with my own tflite?

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I cloned the [Tensorflow's Android image classification example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android) and I want to now use my own tflite that I have downloaded from [here](https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/aiy/vision/classifier/food_V1/1) to classify food. How do I replace the default tflites with my own tflite? I only have one tflite while in the Android example there's a couple so I'm not sure which tflite to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

First, add the model into the [assets](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/models/src/main/assets) folder. Alternatively, you can directly download the model from TFHub in the similar way as [the models in download.gradle](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/models/download.gradle).

Then if you use Task library to run inference (which is simpler), you will need to add a similar class of [ClassifierFloatEfficientNet.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/lib_task_api/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/ClassifierFloatEfficientNet.java) and provide the model info. Register your new class in [Classifier.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/609df9848d8944db8f691e00e76cd6d743a26cc1/lite/examples/image_classification/android/lib_task_api/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/Classifier.java#L83-L91) .

If you use the TFLite Support library to run inference, you'll add the new class like [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/lib_support/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/ClassifierFloatEfficientNet.java).